# Store product from API

Tags: magento2, product, api

I'm using Magento 2.4.3 and tried to store product from API following the docs https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/rest/tutorials/configurable-product/create-simple-products.html

using POST to http://storeurl.com/rest/V1/products

with the raw json code in body

```
{
  "product": {
    "sku": "MS-Champ-S",
    "name": "Champ Tee Small",
    "attribute_set_id": 4,
    "price": 25,
    "status": 1,
    "visibility": 1,
    "type_id": "simple",
    "weight": "0.5"
  }
}
```

however I got an error message

```
{
"message": "\"%fieldName\" is required. Enter and try again.",
"parameters": {
    "fieldName": "searchCriteria"
}
```

How come 'searchCriteria' is required for POST method?
do you have any idea fix that?

Thank you!

Comment: share the code which you try when calling that API.

Comment: @DhirenVasoya I just updated them with code that I send through API

Comment: your request end point url is missing the `store-code` variable. The default store code is `default`. So the request should be https://storeurl/rest/default/V1/products.